# Is Using non dollar prefix variables in Tcl possible?

Tags: python, ruby, variables, tcl

I am working on an novel, automated, EDA issue waiver. The EDA tool/engine in question prints outs devices which set a certain condition, and the condition. The condition looks something like:

```
"uvg -lvs > 7"
```

The condition is almost always made of two strings, 1 begins with a "l2, th e other with a "u", the middle character is "v", the last character can be quite a few letters. The internal engine (which has a Tcl 8.5 API), gets the values of uvg and lvs, and checks them. My algorithm, how however, finds a more realistic difference value (not an absolute value) than the EDA engine finds. I therefore wish to re-evaluate the condition again. I assign values to (in our case) uvg, lvs, and evaluate the condition. Is there a "nicer" way to do that other than:
1. run it in Ruby or Python, where the variables' names do not have to begin with a dollar sign.
2. parse the condition, and add the dollar signs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method might be to use a regular expression substitution to do the dirty work and then feed the result into `expr`:

```
# Sample data; use your own!
set uvg 123; set lvs 321

# Here's the expression we want to evaluate
set theExpression "uvg -lvs > 7"

# Do the evaluation 
set theResult [expr [regsub -all {(\y(?!true\y|false\y)[a-zA-Z]\w*\y)\s*(?![\s(])} $theExpression {$\1}]]

puts "evaluated '$theExpression' to get '$theResult'"
### evaluated 'uvg -lvs > 7' to get '0'
```

The regular expression is a little complicated because we don't want to pick up function calls or numeric or boolean literals.

Note that this is *not* a safe trick at all — it's quite possible to make it *very* confused, and doesn't belong in any general library unless some *very* extensive constraints are placed on the input expression (such as freedom from `$` and `[` characters) — but it may be fine in your environment.

Comment: This is above my regular expression level.. And if it is unsafe/not good for debug, then I will just delegate this to Python/Ruby.
Thanks!